# Read from Firebase to UIpickerView

Tags: swift, firebase, uipickerview

I have some trouble doing the following:

1. Read from Firebase database.
2. Add the information to my UIpickerView as "options"
3. Show "options" in the app.

*What I want to achieve* is to read from "Time report" and display the "user names" as "options" in the UIpickerView (in the "dropdown menu").

(The plan is to later be able to display the information in each of the "options" in the same view. Something like choosing a "User" in a app and having the users "stats" displayed.)

Any help would be great!

**This is my code:**
Well for now, I dont really have code as everything i'v tried seems not to work. Last working code was:

```
    func fetchUser()
{
    ref = Database.database().reference() //Set the reference//

    databaseHandle = ref?.child("Time report").observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in

        print (snapshot)
    })
}
```

**My database looks like:** (Login is the first node. Meaning its the node closest to the root - if that makes any sens.)
[image]
[image]

**My Results** 
Well, for now - I only get Fred, Kalle and Ivar printed, with all their information...

**I've tried:**

- To change "childAdded" to Value. No go..
- Make it work with only one node. Meaning just having "Ivar" and a couple of random values. Printed in console - but nothing in the pickerview.

*Used this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QdLFd3wNqV8) to aid in create a pickerView.*

Comment: Where is `child("Time report")` coming from?  Without seeing the full structure of your Firebase data it's a bit hard to help troubleshoot.  At a quick glance I can tell you that you do want to change from `childAdded` to `value`, and you need to get to `ref.child("Adam")` to be able to see that stuff.  If Adam is a child of "Time report" then you need `child("Time report").child("Adam")`.  As an aside, it's not smart to put spaces in the names of your nodes - it makes things much more difficult to work with.

Comment: @creeperspeak: Ah, ok! Well, Time report is the first "node". And the second node is going to be a name (Adam, Jacob ...). About the naming of nodes - i'll keep that in mind. My understanding is that it may be better to name it the first node "TimeReport".

Comment: Does every user node 'Adam', for example, have child nodes of Home, Work and Gym? Either way, just reading the Adam node by .value and iterating over each child node and reading the key of each child node will give you the nodes of Home, Work and Gym. This is addressed in the Firebase [Work with Lists](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/lists-of-data) guide in the Listen for Value events section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how it's done. I am assuming you know how to populate a dataSource for your pickerView in general. If you need help with that, it would be best addressed as a separate question.

Assume we are using a structure like the one in the original question:

```
  time_report
    adam
      gym
        timestamp_0
          From : "from_0",
          To : "to_0"
        timestamp_1
          From : "from_1",
          To : "to_1"
      home : {
        timestamp_0
          From : "from_0",
          To : "to_0"
      work : {
        timestamp_0
          From : "from_0",
          To : "to_0"
```

Notes:

```
1) best practice is to not use spaces in keys so I am using time_report
2) It's not clear if under each option (gym, home, work) there will be
      multiple nodes so I included two under gym for demonstration purposes
3) I am using placeholders for timestamps from_0, to_0 etc but you get the idea.
4) This will handle any situation for options; they could be gym, home, work
       or A, B, C or whatever the key names are.
5) Nothing is hard coded so as timestamps change, the code continues to work
```

Now to read the options (gym, home, work or whatever they may be) for the adam node here's the code.

```
let timeReportRef = self.ref.child("time_report")
let adamRef = timeReportRef.child("adam")
adamRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
    for child in snapshot.children {
        let snap = child as! DataSnapshot
        let nodeKey = snap.key //will be gym, home, work
        print(nodeKey)
        //populate your dataSource Array here with the nodeKeys
        //the following code could be used to populate a structure with additional
        //  info so when the user taps 'gym', we have already loaded the gym data
        //   and can populate another view controller with the details
        for childTimes in snap.children { //the child nodes under gym, home, work
            let timeSnap = childTimes as! DataSnapshot
            let timeKey = timeSnap.key
            let dict = timeSnap.value as! [String: Any]
            let from = dict["From"] as! String
            let to = dict["To"] as! String

            print("  timestamp: \(timeKey)")
            print("     from: \(from)")
            print("       to: \(to)")
        }
    }
})
```

and the output

```
gym
  timestamp: timestamp_0
     from: from_0
       to: to_0
  timestamp: timestamp_1
     from: from_1
       to: to_1
home
  timestamp: timestamp_0
     from: from_0
       to: to_0
work
  timestamp: timestamp_0
     from: from_0
       to: to_0
```

The important bit here is that if you just want to add gym, home, work to your pickerView, you can omit the For loop. However. That loop demonstrates how to load additional data (timestamps) under gym, home and work.

There's a couple of directions to go from here. If you want to load the firebase data from Firebase when the user taps gym for example, you would get what the user tapped (gym) and you are in the adam section so it would be

```
let user = userSection //assume we are in the 'adam' section
let option = optionTapped //assume the user tapped gym

let userOptionRef = self.ref.child(user).child(option)
userOptionRef.observeSingleEvent(.value.... etc etc to read in that data.
```

Another option would be to read it all in at one time, as in the code I provided)\, and populate a class with that info. Then store the class in a dataSource array to be used in the picker.

```
class userStuff {
   option = ""
   data: DataSnapshot?
}
```

populate that class or stuct within the closure I presented and then store it in an array. Then in your pickerView, as it's being updated, get the userStuff class from the array for the row and read the option text. If the user then taps on row 0, 'gym' read the array, row 0, get the dataSnapshot and iterate over it to populate a sub view with the timestamp info.

Edit

Original question was changed and in response to a comment here:

```
let timeReportRef = self.ref.child("Time report")
timeReportRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
    for child in snapshot.children {
        let snap = child as! DataSnapshot
        print(snap.key)
    }
})
```

output will be

```
Fred
Ivar
Kalle
```

Comment: I'll try it out A.S.A.P. Thank you!

Comment: Tried it out, didn't really work out. So I changed some stuff up to make it easier to understand. Maybe this will help you help me better?

Comment: @Ivar Not sure what the issue actually is as the output as shown in my answer is what you asked for in the original question. You've changed the Firebase structure in the question which actually makes it a different question with a different solution. What I am seeing now is you are asking how to get (print) the three child-node keys under Time Report; Fred, Ivar and Kalle, which is a simple matter of reading in the Time Report node and iterating over the child nodes printing each snapshot.key. Is that what you are asking how to do?

Comment: Well yes, that is want i'am looking to do. You said something about printing the snapshot.key - i'll try that!

Comment: @Ivar I updated answer with a short piece of code to output the three child keys per your request. Don't forget to accept the answer if it helped!

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the fundamentals, please read these two articles:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/structure-data
https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/read-and-write

So this is wrong:

```
  let ProjectInDatabase = snapshot.value as? String
```

An example, lets say you wanted to received the timestamps for Adams home on the "2018-01-27 22:30:07 +0000":

```
 databaseHandle = ref?.child(“Time report”).child(“Adam”).child(“Home”).child("2018-01-27 22:30:07 +0000”).observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in

  //you are getting back a dictionary with all the timestamp values i.e "From" : "2018-01-28 06:00:07 +0000", "To" : "2018-01-28 15:30:07 +0000"

    let ProjectInDatabase = snapshot.value as? Dictionary

     //now lets get the value of the “From” key

    let fromValue = ProjectInDatabase?["From"] as? String ?? ""
```

I dont know the specifics of your app but its worth considering this change:

```
"Adam-Home":{
 "2018-01-27 22:30:07 +0000" : {
    "From" : "2018-01-28 06:00:07 +0000",
    "To" : "2018-01-28 15:30:07 +0000"
  }
 }
 "Adam-Work" : {
  "2018-01-26 22:30:07 +0000" : {
    "From" : "2018-01-28 06:00:07 +0000",
    "To" : "2018-01-28 15:30:07 +0000"
  }
}
```

Structure your database in such a way that everytime you get back only what you need, nothing more!

Comment: Sorry, I was not clear enough. Time report is not the timestamp. Time report is the first node in the DB. Adam is a child of Time report and than the timestamp is another child (of Adam) and in this node we have a "from" and "to" - This is when Adam arrived or "started" the activity. Did that clear stuff up?

Comment: Ok i have edited my answer. It should give you an understanding of where you went wrong and what you need to do now...

Comment: Still not really clear. What I want to do is "be able to se "home", "gym" etc. as options in my UIviewPicker. So that when i choose on of them - it'll display what time Adam entered "From" and exited "To" (See it as start and finish time). How would "Adam-Home" be a smart change? That would mean that for every new place Adam visits - I need to create a "Adam-"newplace""...

Comment: I am not going to tell you how to do all these things, as i am not here to do your work for you. You are asking 3 things, you provide code only for the first one. I answered to that. If you have any questions on that, fire up but be specific!

Comment: How did you answer  "What I want to achieve is to read from "Adam" and display "Home", "Work" and "Gym" as "options" in the UIpickerView (in the "dropdown menu" ? No way, if you ask me. What you told me was how to read of "home" in "Adam" ... That was not really the question was it? Anyways, I solved it. Thank you for ur time!

Comment: Gave you an example to help you understand how to retrieve values! If you are too lazy to adjust to your requirements thats not on me! Good luck you are gonna need it.

Comment: @Ivar I may be mis-reading the question, but how does this answer specifically address the question? The OP wants to read the 'Home', 'Work' and 'Gym' *node keys*  and display them in a UIPicker. i.e. if the node keys were A, B and C, how does this answer demonstrate how to read the string 'A', the string 'B' and the String 'C' and display those strings in a picker view? It's not a bad answer and talks a lot about timestamps but that wasn't the question as far as I can tell.

Comment: @Jay taking your example, i answered how to get the string 'A' (fromValue in my example). I used timestamps as an example as they are the last branch. I also think(per info provided) that the structure is not efficient, hence my last suggestion. Now did i answer how to add and display things in a pickerview? of course not, as the author has not shared any code!

Comment: Hmm. Did you try your code? I did and it doesn't appear to work. The fromValue is *reading the fromValue timestamp node* and does *not* read the node key of 'A' or 'Home' (try it!) More importantly (per my above comment) if the node keys are not the strings "Home" then it won't work for sure as the reference would be wrong. The timestamps are just that; timestamps, so they shouldn't be hard-coded in the observe function reference as that would only work for one specific node. Those timestamps will be different in each node so the code should accommodate that, if not, it would break.

Comment: As a challenge, add a print statement in your code that prints the node keys Home, Work, and Gym to the console. And ensure that it prints the node keys if A, B and C if that's what they are instead. (assuming the node keys may not always be Home Work Gym)

Comment: @Jay But the author will want to get these time values hence my code, so yes it does read the timestamp and not the A, home, etc. And yes you are not supposed to hardcode, I use a function with the node as parameter. I feel as if we are "arguing" why i havent spoon fed,chewed,swallowed and digested the answer so lets just agree to disagree! enjoy your weekend

Comment: Again. Your answer does not address the question and the code doesn't work. Really. It just doesn't work. See my answer which addresses how to retrieve the key names (regardless of what they are), how to load the child timestamp data under each option (regardless of number or name), and also output. The code is tested an verified.

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this. To get their names you can read `snap`'s `key` and then to get their values you can wrangle that data as well.

```
Database.database().reference().child("Time report").observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in
    print(snapshot)
    var item = [String: Any]
    if let snapshots = snapshot.children.allObjects as? [DataSnapshot] {
        for snap in snapshots {
            print(snap)
            item = snap as! [String: Any]
            // do something to save the info - I use datasources
            PageDataSource.sharedInstance.items.append(item)
            completion(nil)
        } else {
        completion(NSError(domain: "Error reading Snapshots", code: 99, userInfo: nil))
    }
}
```